# validate file path using PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate C:\ , D:\, E:\  but the below code accept the different values also.

**Problem**

This code accepts **ASASASD:**, **192.168.10.28:** this is invalid in my case.

```
<?php 

//sting coming as c drive
$string = "C:\\";

//sting coming as d drive
$string1 = "adsasdasdD:\\";

//sting coming as e drive
$string2 = "E:\\";

//validate using reqular expression
preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9:.-]+#", $string1, $out);

//output the string
print_r($out);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That regex matches any string containing just those characters, why would it validate just those drive letters?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9:.-]+ allows one or more occurrence of letter,digit, colon, dot or hyphen.

Comment: I'm not an expert in regex, but this obviously matches anything, even numbers, before the colon.

Comment: Only i have to validate [A-z]: values. only one character should be present in that entry

Comment: The WISE peoples will always put the down votes. I am really happy about that but don't forget to add your reasons this may improve my skills

Comment: @Sundar: I believe somebody might be more willing to help if you just asked straight forward that you need the regex for this pattern. You wrote the question as if you were learning to use regex and couldn't get it to run. It now makes the intent that you're not even trying, sorry to say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single occurrence of any letter, use `[A-Za-z]`. The `+` allows one or more occurrence of preceding pattern.

So what you want is `[A-Za-z]:\\`